# Node.js : Sharing Object between Javascript workers and parent processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, shared-memory, web-worker, worker-thread

I am using js `worker_threads` to utilize threading in Js. I got to know that Js sends a copy of the data which we send to a worker. But it is not memory efficient so I tried to use Shared Memory Between Parent and worker process. I read [this article](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/shared-memory-in-javascript/) for understanding how it can be done. But in my case, I'm gonna share an Object instead of well-known data types.

For sharing an array of numbers we can do it like this:

```
const {Worker} = require("worker_threads");

let nums = [12, 43, 45, 40];

//get size of the array buffer with int32 size buffer for each element in the array
const size = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT*nums.length;

//create the buffer for the shared array
const sharedBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(size);
const sharedArray = new Int32Array(sharedBuffer);

nums.forEach((num, index) => {
  Atomics.store(sharedArray, index, num);
})

//Create new worker
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");

//Listen for a message from worker
worker.on("message", result => {
  console.log(`${result.num}th Fibonacci Number: ${result.fib}`);
});

worker.on("error", error => {
  console.log(error);
});

worker.postMessage({nums: sharedArray});
```

And in the `worker.js` file we can access this data like this whose memory is shared between parent and worker processes:

```
const { parentPort } = require("worker_threads");

parentPort.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.data);
});
```

The data I want in shared memory is like this (similar example):

```
data = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 18,
    marks: [
        {
            name: "Math",
            marks: 100,
        },
        {
            name: "English",
            marks: 90,
        },
        ...
    ],
};
```

There will be multiple workers and they are going to modify the object. For the given example they are going to update marks of some specific subjects. And finally, the parent process is going to save this object into the database.

How can I create Shared Object for the given scenario?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: I want to share an Object. I don't know how I can implement that.

Comment: Memory size is also not fixed for the object.